# Кот или кошка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда мы говорим о кошках, то с динаковой часттой употребляем слово как "кот", так и "кошка" вне зависимости от пола животного.
А есть ли какая-то норма, как все-таки вравильнее говорить о животном (без уточнения пола): кот или кошка?

Answer (score 5):

Вики приводит классификацию :
" Отряд:
Хищные
Подотряд:
Кошкообразные
Семейство:
Кошачьи
Подсемейство :
Малые кошки
Род:
Кошки
Вид:
Лесной кот
Подвид:
**Кошка**

Получается, что дома у нас живут кошки, а в лесу гуляют сами по себе дикие коты.

Answer (score 3):

Я поинтересовался мнением одной знакомой кошатницы. Только что получил интересный ответ.

Домашние - все "женщины", кроме гуся. Дикие, кроме лисы, - "мужчины". 
Возможно, что это связано с менталитетом славян, для которых дом это женщина; лес, охота - мужчина.

Кошак - это разговорное к кот. Норма или почти норма.

Comment: Убедительно. Как  обобщение  и  в  множественном  числе.  Но  есть  другие  исключения -  индюк.  А  лиса  и  лис  в  множественном - лисы. Интересно  с  другими  славянскими  языками  сравнить.

Comment: Рысь  только  женского  рода, хоть  и  опасный  хищник.  Песец  -  только  мужского  рода.

Comment: Ну да, лисы, я и сказал. Вернее - она, знакомая.

Про индюка - не уверен, что не индюшка. Впрочем, этому слову лет не так много. Птичка-то мериканская.

Comment: @bernard, прошу обратить внимание, что разные пола животных называются по-разному в случае необходимости их различения с хозяйственной точки зрения. Например, курица - петух. Петух яйца не несет. Бык - корова. Бык молоко не даст, а корова сама по себе не забеременеет =) ну и т.д.

Касательно вариантов волк - волчица, лев - львица, заяц - зайчиха, кролик - крольчиха и пр., то мне кажется, что они шаблонны и к делу отношения не имеют.

Comment: >что разные пола животных называются по-разному   
  
Я тоже когда-то об этом думала. Все домашние от разных корней: пес-собака-щенок (можно и кобель-сука), конь-лощадь-жеребенок, только кошки, козы и вот гуси с индюками, про которых я забыла, не такие. А дикие - все от одного корня.

Comment: Хочется,  чтобы  было  просто  и  ясно,  но  "просто"  не  получается.  Много  факторов   должно  сработать,  прежде  чем  данное  словоупотребление  закрепится   в  языке.  А  ведь  ещё  есть  и  диалекты.

Answer (score 2):

Чисто  интуитивно  -  кошка.

Answer (score 1):

Слышала такое слово: кошак. Конечно, это не норма, но подходит к любому полу:-)))        Можно ещё "котейко":)))

Comment: Под словом "кошак" мне представляется этакий бандит с подбитым глазом и разоварыннм ухом, ходящий по дворам с выражением: "кому бы набить морду"))) А вот к ммлой домашней кошечке такое вряд ли подойдет)))))

Comment: Есть  ещё  и  котэ !